# Почему не работает loop атрибут в Chrome?

Tags: html, html5, google-chrome

Всем привет

Встроил видео на сайт:

```
<video autoplay id="bgvid" loop>
      <source src="videos/medoff-video.webm" type="video/webm">
      <source src="videos/medoff-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

В мозилле отрабатывает как нужно, но Хром не понимает `loop` и не воспроизводит видео с начала по его окончанию 
Почитал, что проблема в:

> Your server is sending a "200 OK" response, but it should be sending
>   "206 Partial Content"

Но не совсем понял, что это значит.
Какое есть решение этой проблемы?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хром будет воспроизводить это только если в ответе на запрос видео будет статус [`206`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#206).
Этот код говорит что вернул только часть запрошенного и за добавкой нужно снова обращаться с помощью заголовка `Range` ([что это?](https://habrahabr.ru/post/138504/)).

---

Но можно обойтись и без этого небольшим хаком:

```
document.querySelector('video').addEventListener('ended', function(){
  this.load();
  this.play();
});
```

Подглядел [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28729753/6275986).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Ваш пример не заработал, но по клику на ссылку "подгялдел тут" заработал пример

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов, вот какая польза от указания источника! Я просто забыл точку поставить, сейчас будет работать.

Comment: я не настолько туп и точку я ставил) Но ваш не заработал

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов, а ещё в `addEventListener` не требует приставки `on`.